# Commerce Discount Module : Free Products : n+x

Tags: 7, commerce, entities, hooks

Is someone using commerce discount module and customized free products quantity field for buy x and get y functionality ? If i set buy 1 get 1(free product qty) its not multiplying while user updating quantity on cart.for ex-

I added 1 product = 1 qty.if user increase product qty with 2,its remaining same.like 2 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Buy X Get Y offers (or "Per quantity" offers) are supported out of the box in the Commerce Discount Extra module, which we'd like to merge into Commerce Discount eventually:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra